# GRASS tutorials, spec r.walk, r.cost

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grass-gis, cost-path, references

Recently got enamored with the idea of doing a time-based and an energy-based least cost path analysis. After doing some research, I see that GRASS is the best for executing time-based given the k-move functionality. I'm only accustomed to ArcGIS, so I was wondering if there are any GRASS tutorials around that might be helpful, specifically to r.walk, etc.

Some more specifics on what I'm doing: using ASTER gDEM v2 (30m res) in Turkey study area for archaeological project. Doing several points of origin/destination across a mntn range.

Answer (score 2):

For some basic tutorials and exercises for GRASS, you can check this [link](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial_641_en/htdocs/esercitazione/index.html) which I think is a great place for beginners. There are also a couple of other sources which describe the [r.walk](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.walk.html) and [r.cost](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.cost.html) functions and their associated parameters in greater detail (although I'm assuming you have already read these).

Comment: Additionally also http://grass.osgeo.org/documentation/tutorials/

Comment: I have used the following source when I tried to get the hang of `r.walk`: http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/544 .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working through QGIS. Grass itself is quite overwhelming. Still having basic issues with projections, getting a hang of the data structure and executing r.walk.

Thanks all.